# How to make half sliding drawer?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

how to make sliding drawer like below from left to right and right to left.This should be done in both side when click on button.without Action bar and after sliding from left to right part of list should be seen in right side

[image]

Comment: euhm, could you rephrase that?

Comment: why don't you reread it instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [Android Navigation Drawer](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)
2. **Recommended: ** [SlidingMenu Library](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a side menu navigation drawer using ActionBarSherlock Library

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/implementing-actionbarsherlock-side-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android/

Comment: is it possible without action bar?

Comment: Yes in place of action bar you can use the SupportActionBar().

Comment: And it will support in all version of api